# Finding the median

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice, median

I have a following problem to solve:
**Let X be a random variable equal to a greater dice number when throwing two symmetric dices with values from 1 to 6. What is the median of X?**
I'm not quite sure if I understand the exercise correctly. I know that number 2 can occur two times (when throwing 1 and 2 or 2 and 1), number 3 can occur four times(1-3, 2-3, 3-2, 3-1) etc. but I don't know what to do with cases 1-1, 2-2, etc. Am I supposed to ignore them as there is no greater number? Does it mean that we have 30 possible cases?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what $X$ is?

Comment: There are $36$ possible outcomes. List them from smallest to largest. Compute the median.

Comment: @AndrewZhang $X$ is the higher of the two values thrown, so $X=2$ when you throw $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$ or $(2,2)$, i.e. three ways rather than the two suggested.  Similarly $X=3$ can happen with five rather than four of the possible pairs of throws.  Note $1+3+5+7+9+11=36$ and $9+11 > \frac{36}{2}$

Comment: I think the problem is a bit badly worded; I believe in the case of $1-1$ or similar you are supposed to take $1$ as the "greater value". Usually such things are written out explicitly, but I'd imagine the problem writer assumed that you would know to do this. Now, just follow @AnonSubmitter85's comment.